# How to start multiple rootless Xorg instances in Linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, multiple-instances

I'm trying to start 2 Xorg instances on different tty's. I'd like to run LXDE on tty1 with normal 1280x800 resolution and minecraft on separate Xorg server on tty2 with 640x400 resolution. That way I could switch between desktop (internet browser for example) and minecraft using Ctrl+Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Alt+F2. This will automatically switch my screen resolution. I need to run minecraft at lower resolution to get better FPS (difference is very noticable). **Edit: This method doesn't work with minecraft, it freezes when it's minimized or on not displayed Xorg**
There is a probem: when I run Xorg rootless, I can only run it one at a time. Second Xorg fails with `Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE)`. In ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log there is error: `(EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].` Here is full log:

```
[ 12537.302] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 12537.303] Current Operating System: Linux localhost.localdomain 5.13.19_1 #1 SMP Sat Sep 18 18:18:26 UTC 2021 x86_64
[ 12537.304] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.19_1 root=UUID=fa09ee21-d0dd-4c1e-a1b9-da255b55b480 ro quiet tsc=unstable
[ 12537.306]  
[ 12537.306] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[ 12537.306]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 12537.307] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 12537.311] (==) Log file: "/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Thu Sep 29 19:12:38 2022
[ 12537.316] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 12537.316] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 12537.323] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 12537.323] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 12537.323] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 12537.324] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 12537.324] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 12537.325] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 12537.325] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 12537.325] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 12537.326] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 12537.326] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 12537.327] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/OTF" does not exist.
[ 12537.327]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12537.329] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi
[ 12537.329] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[ 12537.329] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 12537.330] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 12537.330]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 12537.330]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[ 12537.330]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[ 12537.331]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 12537.338] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 12537.338] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[ 12537.481] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:2a42:17aa:3a02 rev 7, Mem @ 0xf4000000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00001800/8, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 12537.483] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:1) 8086:2a43:17aa:3a02 rev 7, Mem @ 0xf4400000/1048576
[ 12537.485] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[ 12537.485] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 12537.488] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 12537.502] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12537.502]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.0
[ 12537.503]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 12537.503] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 12537.503] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 12537.504] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 12537.504] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[ 12537.504] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 12537.505] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[ 12537.512] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[ 12537.516] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12537.516]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.99.917
[ 12537.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 12537.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12537.518] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 12537.524] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 12537.533] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12537.533]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.21.1
[ 12537.534]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 12537.534]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12537.535] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 12537.541] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 12537.543] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12537.543]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[ 12537.544]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 12537.544]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12537.544] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[ 12537.551] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 12537.553] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12537.553]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[ 12537.554]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 12537.554]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12537.554] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[ 12537.568] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[ 12537.568] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[ 12537.569] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[ 12537.569] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 12537.570] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 12537.571] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[ 12537.572] (++) using VT number 2

[ 12537.574] xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
[ 12537.576] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20201103
[ 12537.591] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[ 12537.592] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[ 12537.592] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[ 12537.592] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 12537.594] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[ 12537.595] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12537.596]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 0.0.2
[ 12537.596]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12537.597] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[ 12540.475] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
[ 12540.477] (EE) intel(0): Failed to claim DRM device.
[ 12540.477] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[ 12540.479] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[ 12540.479] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 12540.481] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[ 12540.484] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 12540.486] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[ 12540.487] (EE) 
[ 12540.510] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

In `LC_ALL=C strace -ftt startx` there are `ioctl(11, DRM_IOCTL_SET_VERSION, 0x7fff68944c20) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)` and `clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=1000000}, NULL) = 0` repeated a lot of times. Here is link to full strace (too big to post here) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B2Ck-C3S2n5KSGcgl50MY6UhG6PYw961/view?usp=sharing
Can I somehow give user rights to failing set drm interface version command without giving Xorg root? (like adding it to video and input group)
My laptop is Lenovo G530 with Intel Pentium dual core T3400 1.0 to 2.16 GHz, Intel GM 45 integrated graphics. I'm using Linux Void x86_64 glibc.
If someone is curious: yes I have a better computer, but getting things working right on older one is cool for me.

Comment: The code which emits the error is here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-intel/-/blob/31486f40f8e8f8923ca0799aea84b58799754564/src/intel_device.c#L719

Comment: Yes it's the `drmIoctl(dev->fd, DRM_IOCTL_SET_VERSION, &sv);` that fails but is it possible to make it work as non root user? And what is `dev`? `/dev/dri/card0`?